# node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' as it does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradlew

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/milanshrestha/Documents/work/hermes/mobile/HermesMobileV2/hermesmobile/android/app/build.gradle' line: 86
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not read script '/Users/milanshrestha/Documents/work/hermes/mobile/HermesMobileV2/hermesmobile/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' as it does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

I am facing this issue while running android app i got this issue after upgrading some libs on my project in ios its working fine after some fixes but i got stuck in this. Also after trying all solution from stack overflow questions.

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 5):

follow this:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36643#issuecomment-1685371108

Then in android > app > build.gradle:
comment-out/delete the line

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

if it exists

then run `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well - after updating a number of libraries.

I was able to get around this by backing-up/removing my project's "android" folder (which was acceptable in my case given that I did not have any specific customizations for it), running the prebuild command with a "--clean" flag so as to regenerate the "android" folder like so:

```
npx expo prebuild -p android --clean
```

(It took a while for that to complete!)

And subsequently, I re-ran the "npx expo run:android" and all was fine.